Finding poles of the transimpedance amplifier
I`ve been having problems with finding poles of one transimpedance amplifier.
Acording to LTSpice the first pole should be somewhere around 1.6MHz, but I cant get that (I am getting about 200MHz). I will put some pictures of the circuit and the my calculations on it.
Can you help me find the problem?




Assuming your math is correct, your poles are going to be where the denominator of your transfer function is going to be zero. With the information you have given us so far, you cannot find a numerical value because there's no information about what your resistor values are. Also, I see a variable $C$ even though I don't see a capacitor anywhere.

Values are as follows
Rc=1kOhm
Rf=10kOhm
rpi2=8kOhm
C=10^-12F
R1=4.444kOhm
gm1=5010^-3
β=400
Capacitors are included in Z1 and Z2, parallel to resistors R1 and R2

Your handwriting is impossible for me to read clearly even after considerable magnification. This is why we use Latex/mathjax for making formulas: $x = \frac{-b \pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ is \$x = \frac{-b \pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\$ ||| I advise you to use it and make your component IDs clearer.

I am sorry for the bed writing, I didnt know for th Latex/mathjax, I will keep that in mind for later. Thank you for the time
